# Web to Lead error message display

Tags: javascript, force.com, web2lead, sales-cloud

I have a `web-to-lead` html form (generated form standard Salesforce functionality) and a duplicate rule.

I want to display a success and error message that whether lead is created or not after clicking on submit.

Answer (score 0):

No because lead data goes into queue, after that what happens that html page doesn't know, so we can't do that